# Is there a way to manually insert records into InfluxDB with custom timestamps via telegraf?

Tags: influxdb, stackdriver, telegraf

https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/pull/1557

Apparently some people have been asking for this, and this Github PR is the closest thing I can find to a solution, but it was ultimately denied(I think?).

Basically, I have a JSON object I'm getting from Stackdriver, which includes a Timestamp in ISO8601, which I convert to Unix time. I can insert the entire JSON response into Influx fine, but the timestamp from Stackdriver appears as a tag for a series, rather than the index of the time series itself. As a result, it is unfeasible to query by Stackdriver's provided timestamp. I could simply just drop it, and use the Influx provided timestamp, but it is essentially querying incorrect/imprecise data.

Does anyone have a clever way to approach this?

**tl;dr How can I use Telegraf to override InfluxDB's timestamps with my own timestamps?**